# SDL2 taskbar icon notification (blinking / flashing orange)?

Tags: sdl2

In steam when you get a message, or in CS:GO when you find a match the taskbar icon flashes orange and your taskbar becomes unhidden if that's how you have it setup.

In SDL2 you can set a window icon fairly easily, but is there a way to notify the user such as bringing "up" the taskbar?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe `SDL_RaiseWindow()` could work.

Comment: I've tried it and I'm pretty certain it only raises 1 window above other SDL2 windows, doesn't affect taskbar icon, nor does it even raise the window if it's minimized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE (2021):**

SDL 2.0.16 has added [`SDL_FlashWindow`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_FlashWindow), which handles this in a cross-platform way.

**OLD ANSWER:**

No, sadly SDL doesn't have built-in functionality for this.

However, implementing this doesn't seem to be too difficult, at least for Windows. Something like the following should work:

```
SDL_SysWMinfo systemInfo; SDL_VERSION(&systemInfo.version);
SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(m_Window, &systemInfo);

FLASHWINFO flash;
flash.cbSize = sizeof(FLASHWINFO);
flash.hwnd = systemInfo.info.win.window;
flash.dwFlags = FLASHW_TIMERNOFG;  // Flashes until the window is focused.
flash.uCount = 1;
flash.dwTimeout = 100;  // The flash interval in milliseconds.
FlashWindowEx(&flash);
```

I'm sure resources can be found for doing this on other platforms from the internet.